# Database Lookup on string or auto-increment id

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a database where I am using an auto-increment field as the primary key. However, there is another field, studyUID, that will definitely be unique to the table. This studyUID, however, is a string and is typically around 60 characters in length. My thought, perhaps incorrectly, is that it would be faster or better to use the integer from the auto-inc field as the primary key - maybe I thought that is just what you do.

As I’m writing this I’m thinking maybe this doesn’t make sense as I will almost always search the database using the studyID field. Based on that logic, maybe it doesn’t even make sense to have the auto-inc field.

Would appreciate comments and thoughts on this subject.

Comment: Using an auto-increment key also forces me to always perform an id lookup after inserting the new row. Using the studyID would make this unnecessary.

Comment: Using the auto-increment key is useful when you use foreign keys. Just ensure a unique index on the studyID. However, it perfectly ok to use studyID as the primary key.

Comment: Ryan, good point with the foreign key issue. In that case, if I were to use just the studyID I’d have to also place the studyID in the related table. Would that relationship slow down the searches etc. considering the key is now a 60 character value?

Comment: It would certainly take up quite a lot more room in index if used as a foreign key. I don't think it slow down searches that much. Depend how many rows you have really. Do not design your database with performance considerations initially. Test it with 'live' volumes of data later to find out if you have issues.